# Revert several migrations from database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-6.0

I've made several database migrations that need to be undone.

I know I can use `remove-migration` to remove each migration until I get back to the one I want. But how can I also remove those migrations from the database?

I found the following command on stackoverflow:

```
update-database -targetmigration: 20211217211526_AddedClmRailcarIndex
```

But this gives me an error.

> Update-Database : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'targetmigration'.

Apparently, this is an outdated way to do it.

How can I revert the database?

Comment: it's [`dotnet ef database update MigrationName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update)

Answer (score 1):

For EF Core, the parameter is `-migration`, not `-targetmigration`:
[EF Core tools reference (Package Manager Console) - EF Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#update-database)

You can omit the parameter name, and the migration ID is optional.

```
update-database -migration AddedClmRailcarIndex
```